# #define <anyName> '\n' instead of '\n'

Tags: c++

I was wondering if `#define nd '\n'` is an acceptable alternative to good old `'\n'` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#define nd '\n'
int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello World !" << nd ;
}
```

I feel this would come handy while printing variables or iterators, does save a few keystrokes.

Comment: Acceptable for what?  For obfuscation?  If you want a newline, print a newline.  If you want to flush the buffer after a newline, use `std::endl`

Comment: `std:endl` is not just `\n`

Comment: @tas for simpler usage "\n", yes std::endl can be used if it needed.

Comment: That'd just cause way more problems when the project you're working on gets bigger and more complicated.

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes I was pointing it out for cases where the user doesn't want to flush the buffer.

Comment: @P0W I do agree it's not just \n , I was pointing out a use case where the user wants to use "\n" with minimal key strokes.

Comment: @DeanSeo true, that was my doubt. I guess it works for a closed environment such as competitive programming.

Comment: more shorter `std::cout << "Hello World !\n";` ?

Comment: @mnciitbhu I agree it is shorter when the output is a string, I was thinking in cases where cout << iterator << "\n"  is used.

Comment: #define nd std::endl

Comment: Are you asking whether it works or whether it's acceptable? The latter is subjective. The compiler certainly accepts it. Microsoft Word accepts it, but PowerPoint doesn't unless I put it in a textbox. My analogue phone doesn't accept it because it doesn't have a ' button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, I suppose, some use for a manipulator that does "write a new line without a flush", not to save keystrokes, but because the naive version (`os << '\n'` or `os << "\n"`) may produce undesirable padding if `os.width()` is greater than 1, and writing `os.put('\n')` is annoying.

So:

```
template<class charT, class traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& newl(std::basic_ostream<charT, traits>& os) {
    return os.put(os.widen('\n'));
}
```

As to your macro, that's just pointless obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if `#define nd '\n'` is an acceptable alternative to
>   good old `std::endl` ?

Not really. `std::endl` does two things:

1. Print newline
2. Flush stream

Whereas your solution does only the former, so it's not equivalent.

On the other hand, compared to literal '\n', this macro saves so little keystrokes while increasing confusion that I would consider it doing more harm than good.

Comment: Yes it is true, I should have rephrased my question as a replacement to 
 << "\n" ;

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Not acceptable. If you want a newline, just type the `'\n'`, and if you want to also flush the buffer use `std::endl`. Nobody reading your code is going to know what your macro means, and no significant effort will be saved on your own part.

Comment: yes agreed, I was curious to know how useful the approach is.